# Why is image rotated in SVG?

Tags: svg, rotation

I have this SVG output:
http://www.angliru.nl/kaftschoon/143/
The original photo is: http://www.angliru.nl/upload/IMG_IX3346.JPG

The original photo is standing. The photo is still standing after uploading. But when placed in a SVG the photo is rotated sideways.
Why? And how to prevent it? I'm scratching my head on that one.

```
   <svg version="1.1" id="Laag_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
    width="447" height="833"
viewBox="265 90 311.9 495.3" enable-background="new 0 0 841.9 595.3" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
    <defs>
        <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="842" height="595">
            <image xlink:href="http://www.angliru.nl/upload/IMG_IX3346.JPG" x="0" y="0"
                width="842" height="595" style="max-width:842px; max-height: 595px; min-width: 842px; min-height: 595px;" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <path d="M549.9,476.2c-3.3,0-6.1,0-8.9,0c-15.2,0-30.3-0.1-45.5,0.1c-2.3,0-5,1.3-6.8,2.9c-3.6,3-6.7,6.5-10,9.8
        c-3.2,3.1-6.4,3.3-9.5,0c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.2-0.3-0.4c-7.5-11.2-18.1-13.6-31-12.6c-13.6,1-27.3,0.1-41,0.3c-2,0-4.4,1.1-6,2.5
        c-3.5,3-6.6,6.6-10,9.8c-3.9,3.7-7.1,4.1-10.1-0.1c-7.9-10.9-18.3-13.5-31.1-12.5c-12.8,1-25.6,0.2-38.5,0.1
        c-0.3,0-0.6-0.2-1.5-0.6c0-11.7,0-23.6,0-35.6c0-7.7,0.3-15.3-0.1-23c-0.1-2.3-1.4-5-3-6.8c-3.7-4.3-8-8-11.9-12.1
        c-3.7-3.9-3.6-6.3,0.1-10.2c0.2-0.2,0.4-0.5,0.7-0.7c12.3-8.5,16.2-20,14.5-34.8c-1.3-11,0-22.3-0.3-33.4c-0.1-2.4-1.3-5.1-2.9-7
        c-3.9-4.9-8.4-9.4-12.6-14.2c-2.5-2.9-2.3-5.6,0.5-8.3c4.1-3.9,8.3-7.7,12-12c1.6-1.8,2.8-4.6,2.8-7c0.2-16.7,0.2-33.3,0-50
        c0-2.2-1.2-4.8-2.6-6.5c-3.7-4.5-7.9-8.6-11.9-12.8c-3.5-3.8-3.4-6,0.2-9.8c2.4-2.5,4.5-5.5,7.2-7.6c6.8-4.9,7.6-11.5,7.4-19.3
        c-0.4-15.8-0.1-31.6-0.1-47.7c7.3,0,14.4,0,21.5,0c10.8,0,21.6,0.2,32.5,0.1c1.1,0,2.5-0.7,3.3-1.6c4.4-4.5,8.6-9.3,13-13.8
        c4.2-4.3,6.9-4.2,11-0.1c5.1,4.9,9.5,11.8,15.7,14.3c6.2,2.5,14.1,0.6,21.3,0.7c10.5,0,21,0.3,31.5,0c2.5-0.1,5.4-1.4,7.3-3
        c4-3.5,7.5-7.6,11.2-11.4c4.6-4.6,7.2-4.7,11.8-0.2c2.3,2.2,4.9,4.2,6.7,6.7c5,7.1,11.9,8.4,19.9,8.3c12.7-0.3,25.3,0,38,0
        c1.5,0,2.9,0,5.2,0c0,10.7,0,21,0,31.3c0,8.7-0.3,17.3-0.1,26c0,1.8,1.2,3.9,2.5,5.3c4,4.2,8.3,8.1,12.5,12.3c3.2,3.2,3,6.4,0,9.7
        c-1.5,1.6-2.8,3.3-4.6,4.6c-8.7,6.2-11.1,14.5-10.5,25c0.8,13.5,0.2,27,0.5,40.5c0,1.9,1,4.2,2.3,5.6c3.8,4.2,7.9,8.1,11.9,12.1
        c4,4,3.9,7,0,11.1c-2,2-3.7,4.4-6,6c-7.4,5.1-8.8,12.2-8.5,20.7c0.6,14.3-0.1,28.7,0.1,43c0,2.2,1.3,4.7,2.8,6.4
        c3.8,4.4,8.1,8.3,12.1,12.6c2.7,2.9,2.6,6-0.2,8.9c-3.7,3.8-7.4,7.6-11.3,11.3c-2.5,2.3-3.4,4.9-3.3,8.3
        C550,436.7,549.9,456.1,549.9,476.2z"
        fill="url(#img1)" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: As a pointer, you might be tripping over an issue with the EXIF data, which can include an orientation field. Randomly selected link describing the issue - http://keyj.emphy.de/exif-orientation-rant/

Comment: It looks like it. I downloaded this photo, opened it with photoshop and saved it again. 
Now the image is standing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue comes down to the EXIF data stored against the original image.

EXIF - [Exchangable image file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) - is a set of metadata relating to the image itself, stored alongside it in the same file. The data can be quite comprehensive, covering for example:

- GPS coordinates of the location
- Camera hardware
- Camera settings (ISO, etc)
- Orientation

It's this last one that you're tripping over, and it's quite likely in this case that the phone was being held sideways when this photograph was taken. Your web browser is respecting the Orientation setting, and is rotating it accordingly; the SVG processor on the other hand is ignoring it.

That's the "why" part handled.

The "how to prevent" is more complicated, and without knowing more about how the image ended up in your system it's impossible to answer precisely.

Obviously you've discovered that loading it into Photoshop and re-saving has fixed the issue (Photoshop has stripped out the orientation tag), but for a longer-term solution you will need to process your uploaded images; a tool such as [Exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) should suffice for this.